# classList.add (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, css, class

Why does this not work?

```
const desktop = document.getElementsByClassName("desktop");
```

```
const enableDarkMode = () => {
    desktop.classList.add('night_mode');
}
```

In the console it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined".
**How can I fix it?**

Comment: `desktop` is a collection, not a single element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a *collection*, not a single element. Therefore, you need to iterate over your node list and apply the class.

Example:

```js
const divs = document.getElementsByClassName("desktop");
for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  const div = divs[i];
  div.classList.add('night_mode');
}
```

```css
.night_mode {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="desktop">Desktop</div>
<div class="desktop">Desktop</div>
<div class="desktop">Desktop</div>
<div class="desktop">Desktop</div>
<div class="desktop">Desktop</div>
<div class="desktop">Desktop</div>
```